# How to use fragment into another fragment in Android

Tags: android

In my application I have `fragment` and I want to use this `fragment` into another fragment! 
I write below codes, but when open fragment shows me force close error. 
**My code:**

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(
            R.id.calendarContainer, calendar, PersianCaldroidFragment::class.java.name
        ).commit()
}
```

**Error message:**

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.ensureExecReady(FragmentManager.java:1686)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1716)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:317)
        at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter$FragmentMaxLifecycleEnforcer.updateFragmentMaxLifecycle(FragmentStateAdapter.java:726)
        at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter$FragmentMaxLifecycleEnforcer$3.onStateChanged(FragmentStateAdapter.java:657)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:360)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:271)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:313)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:151)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:134)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:3167)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start(FragmentStateManager.java:588)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:279)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1424)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2968)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:2893)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:3171)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start(FragmentStateManager.java:588)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:279)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1424)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2968)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:2893)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:274)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:359)
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing `parentFragmentManager` with `childFragmentManager`

Comment: Thanks, but after change fragment manager show me this error : `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.myapp.views.persian_calendar.persian.caldroidfragment.PersianCaldroidFragment.getViewPagerPosition()' on a null object reference
        at com.myapp.views.persian_calendar.persian.caldroidfragment.MonthFragment.onCreateView(MonthFragment.java:95)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3104)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:524`

Comment: I used this library : https://github.com/dariushm2/PersianCaldroid/blob/master/libs/lib_PersianCaldroid/src/main/java/com/dariushm2/PersianCaldroid/caldroidfragment/MonthFragment.java

Comment: Seems like a problem with your other fragment, might be hard to find a problem without the code (also It would be worth to open a new question)